# How does an atom acquire momentum when it absorbs a photon?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, photons

When an electron of an atom absorbs a photon of energy E, momentum p=E/c, what is the momentum increase in the atom. Is the vector momentum increase be given by magnitude p = E/c and direction is the direction of the incoming photon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes - due to momentum conservation of the whole system.